# How to iterate XML-formatted string through "foreach" loop in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, string, foreach

I have string in XML format with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251" ?>
<Operation>
<PersonOperation>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Phone>79161234586</Phone>
    <City>Glasgow</City>    
    <Date>2014-02-03</Date>
    <OperationType>Join</OperationType>
    <Amount>9000.00</Amount>
</PersonOperation>
<PersonOperation>
    <Name>Bill Satly</Name>
    <Phone>78263211334</Phone>
    <City>London</City>
    <Date>2014-07-10</Date>
    <OperationType>Stock</OperationType>
    <Amount>3000.00</Amount>
</PersonOperation>
```

How can I iterate this string through "foreach" loop in C# and check if the value of OperationType node is equal to "Join"?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is to load it via an XML API, e.g. LINQ to XML, then you can really easily query it. Is there any reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: Yesterday, you couldn't create this xml. Now you can't read it?

Comment: I've created it for today morning.

Answer (score 0):

Load the string into an XmlDocument and use the SelectNodes() method with the appropriate XPath query.

Query to iterate:

"Operation/PersonOperation"

Comment: Call of SelectNodes produces XPathException

Comment: @user3769902 How did you try exactly? Update your question with the codes you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a LinqToXml query, like this:

```
  var result = document.Root.Elements()
                       .Where(b => b.Element("OperationType").Value == "Join");
```